# border gradient in chrome

Tags: css

You sent code border gradients which is running in mozilla. But it is not working in webkit browser. Can you tell me the code that is runnable in webkit browser for border gradients?

Comment: Who sent them? What are they? Can you post the code that works in Mozilla?

Answer (score 2):

Gradients for border images are currently not working correctly in -webkit. In fact, only basic border-image support via the border-image shortcut syntax is working in Webkit browsers. You will need to hack together using nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a parent div with a padding of the width you want the border to have and then just set the parent div's background to:

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(black));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that:

```
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #66cc00)) 21 30 30 21 repeat repeat;
```

Will do the job for you. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/MWaTw/ for more examples

Comment: Actually this gives a good example of how broken gradient border images are: http://jsfiddle.net/TQ8w3/

Comment: And this gives a good example of understanding the syntax:

http://jsfiddle.net/eatchocolate/MWaTw/

Ofcourse it wont work in all browsers and zoom levels, but its possible

Comment: So all you have to do is explicitly set border height and width in pixels and the gradients behave? (I don't quite get your point on "understanding the syntax" - "border: 20px" is a legal short-form).